# Could not load file or assembly 'RevitApi' version = 19.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls, .net-assembly

I've been creating an add-in for the program 'Revit' for the past few weeks now. It all went fine, but all of a sudden, whenever I try to set the `DataSource` of my `DataGridView` to my class `getEntiteitenData`, I get the error :

> *Error using the dropdown: Could not load file or assembly 'RevitAPI, Version=19.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I did not change the files location or anything, and the `.dll` is loaded in all the classes. Also, I have used this method on another `DataGridView` and it worked fine. The only difference I can tell  so far, is the one where it works, it is an `Windows Form`, the other, where it doesn't work, it's an `user control`

The most annoying thing about this is, when it gives the error, it shuts down my visual studio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Did you change the assemblies property specific version to false? This will prevent your application load previous versions of that component.

Comment: Yes I did, doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: And use an assembly resolver?

Comment: I am not familiar with that to be honest, is that an function within visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Add this line to the main class of your application. This must be called before anything.

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

Add this code to you aplication.

```
static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            string assemblyFullName;

            System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyName;

            assemblyName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
            assemblyFullName = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                System.IO.Path.Combine(
                    System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), <You folder>), assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
            else
                return null;
        }
```

This will load only the assemblies in the folder of your application or the folder defined by you

Comment: I tried adding it, but the line  'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);' won't work. What I don't understand, that if i'm building the code, it's working fine. The issue is when I bind a datasource, all of a sudden he will close the program and gives the error.

Comment: What kind of erro do you have?

Comment: This is the error:

The Name 'AppDoman.CurrentDoman.AssemblyResolve' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Do you have the resolver in the main class? Do you have this namespace `using System;`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the problem was only occuring when i'm binding the data from the designer window. I tried binding it by code, and this worked !

After I added this to my Designer.Cs:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource getEntiteitenDataBindingSource3;
this.getEntiteitenDataBindingSource3 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.getEntiteitenDataBindingSource3)).BeginInit();
this.entiteitenGrid.DataSource = this.getEntiteitenDataBindingSource3;
this.getEntiteitenDataBindingSource3.DataSource = typeof(getEntiteitenData);
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.getEntiteitenDataBindingSource3)).EndInit();
```

Everything seems to work now, and the Columns I wanted to bind are actual visual in the designer now.

Comment: Nevermind, whenever I load the user control to my main form. it generates the same kind of error. Really annoyed with this because I'm really not sure how to fix this.